# Openbravo source code errors

Tags: java-ee-6, openbravo

Hi i am new in Openbravo development and trying to configure it.

I have checkout the source code of openbravo form
[Openbravo](https://code.openbravo.com/erp/devel/main)

and run successfully `ant istall.source` and find `BUILD Successfully` message in command prompt.

So I import it in Eclipse but the main Openbravo project has shows errors in source files

i.e it has some missing libraries and folders e.g:

```
import org.openbravo.client.application.process.BaseProcessActionHandler can't find the folder
```

and many other such libraries.

Please help me to resolve this errors.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have a detailed information in the wiki documents. Consider the following links for setting up Openbravo in eclipse IDE. 
**[Set up in Eclipse IDE](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/How_to_setup_Eclipse_IDE)** 
Here is a page from Openbravo's **[Developer guide](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/ERP_2.50%3aDevelopers_Guide/Development_Environment/Setting_up_Development_Environment_with_Eclipse_IDE#Import_into_Eclipse_IDE)**